# how to get the index of an element in pyspark with the help of the second column?

Tags: pyspark

how to use `array_position` to get the right index with the help of the second column??

example:

```
col1                                col2             
['apple','sib','mive','banana']     'sib'     
['jasmin','df','nagh']               'nagh'
['jk']                                na
```

output

```
col1                                col2             index 
['apple','sib','mive','banana']     'sib'             1
['jasmin','df','nagh']               'nagh'           2
['jk']                                na              na
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `expr` function to achieve it.

```
df = df.withColumn('index', F.expr('array_position(col1, col2) - 1'))
```